# Galaxy, HTSeq error - uninitialized value

Tags: sequencing

I am very new to RNAseq analysis. I am trying to run HTSeq using Galaxy as I am unfamiliar with coding and how to do this with Python.

**I get the following error:**

```
Use of uninitialized value $input_file in concatenation (.) or string at /mnt/galaxyTools/shed_tools/toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repos/fcaramia/edger/86292c2b0ba9/edger/htseq.pl line 57.

Usage: file [-bchikLlNnprsvz0] [--apple] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type]
            [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ...
       file -C [-m magicfiles]
       file [--help]

Use of uninitialized value $input_file in concatenation (.) or string at /mnt/galaxyTools/shed_tools/toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repos/fcaramia/edger/86292c2b0ba9/edger/htseq.pl line 62.
```

**This is followed by a long list of where the error is found. For example:**

```
Error occured when reading first line of sam file.

Error: 
[Exception type: StopIteration, raised in count.py:81]

Use of uninitialized value $sample in hash element at /mnt/galaxyTools/shed_tools/toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repos/fcaramia/edger/86292c2b0ba9/edger/htseq.pl line 67.

Use of uninitialized value $files[0] in string eq at /mnt/galaxyTools/shed_tools/toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repos/fcaramia/edger/86292c2b0ba9/edger/htseq.pl line 78.
```